# Python select with _mysql module without an error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I need to use _mysql, but i don't know how to get all the output of my selection without an error.

```
db = sql.connect(host=host,user=user,passwd=pw,db=dbName)
db.query(query)
rows = db.use_result()
while rows:
    result = rows.fetch_row()[0]
    print result
```

with this code i get all the data but also this:

```
 result = rows.fetch_row()[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

When i use `db.store_result` the same happens.

How do i get all the output without an error?

edit:
My problem is, that the while is running endless.
So how do i know if there are no more resultrows?

possible solution:

```
 while 1:
     result = rows.fetch_row()
     if result:
         print result[0]
     else:
         break
```

Do you have any better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nicer way to do it is:

```
while i < rows.num_rows():
    i+=1
    result = rows.fetch_row()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `[0]` from `result = rows.fetch_row()[0]` like `result = rows.fetch_row()`.

**Edited:**

```
db = sql.connect(host=host,user=user,passwd=pw,db=dbName)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()
for result in results:
    print result[0]
```

Comment: That's not very helpfull.
row.fetch_row returns something like ((result,result),)

Comment: sorry, i edited my comment.
now i know my problem..
my while doesn't stop.. and when there are no more results there is just (). with your solution, i get the whole tuple and the while will run endless.

Comment: Updated my answer, check it again pls.

Comment: I have to use _mysql. You used the mysqldb module.

Comment: @Luca Your solution is definitely right, but  I think you should switch module `_mysql` to `mysqldb`.

Comment: Yeah would be better.. but my colleagues aren't able to install it on the linux machine, i have to run my script.
Anyway.. thanks for your help